# How can I determine a timezone by the UTC offset and convert the UTC timestamp to any other timezone in Java8?

Tags: datetime, java-8, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset, zoneddatetime

I have a UTC timestamp  "2021-02-11T09:00:01-07:00" and I need to get the zone id on the basis of the offset.
The logic should be able to fetch the correct timezone based on any given offset.
So that I can convert any UTC timestamp to any other ZonedDateTime.
Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

A time-zone offset is the amount of time that a time-zone differs from Greenwich/UTC. This is usually a fixed number of hours and minutes, so you can get the offset from `OffsetDateTime` and get the `ZoneId` having matching offset

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(time);

System.out.println(dateTime.getOffset().getId());

ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().forEach(z->{
        if(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(z)).getOffset().equals(dateTime.getOffset())){
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    });
```

**Note :** As per my knowledge there might be multiple zoneId's having same offset, so you probably need the country to filter the zoneId's to pick the correct one.

Comment: this is for America. I can see for America itself it has many options.